# using strcmp with an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strcmp

Here is the full code. it keeps freezing now

```
 typedef struct {
     char *name;
} NAME;
```

setting the array to be null and then later on i expand it depending on how many entries i need to add.

```
NAME    *array = NULL;
int itemCount = 0; // items inserted
int arraySize = 0; // size of array
int arrayCount; //gets size of file.
int found = 0;

int Add(NAME item)
{
if(itemCount == arraySize) {

    if (arraySize == 0)
        arraySize = 3;
    else
        arraySize *= 2; // double size of array

    //relocate memory
    void *tempMemory = realloc(array, (arraySize * sizeof(NAME)));

    //error relocating memory
    if (!tempMemory)
    {
        printf("Couldn't relocate the memory \n");
        return(-1);
    }

    array = (NAME*)tempMemory;
}

array[itemCount] = item;
itemCount++;

return itemCount;
}
   void printStruct()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", array[i].name);
    }
}

int readFromFile()
{
    int checkResult(char[]);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("names.txt", "r");

    char names[arrayCount];

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot access file \n");
    }else{
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", names);
            arrayCount++;
            checkResult(names);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
    }


int checkResult(char names[]){
    NAME tempStruct;

    int i;
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        tempStruct.name = malloc((strlen(names) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tempStruct.name, names);
        tempStruct.count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
        {
            if(strncmp(array[i].name, names, arrayCount)==0)
            {
                printf("MATCH %s", names);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(i == arrayCount)
        {
            tempStruct.name = malloc((strlen(names) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(tempStruct.name, names);
        }


        if (Add(tempStruct) == -1)
        {
                return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the main i am freeing the memory and calling the other functions

```
int main(){
    void printStruct();
    int readFromFile();
    readFromFile();

    printStruct();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        free(array[i].name);
    }

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, for the love of our sanity, post a complete compileable code example that shows your problem.

Comment: Your code as presented does an insert for all elements with a firstName that doesn't match.

Comment: yeah. if the name does not match any of the items in the array it is inserted

Answer (score 3):

What we're doing here is looping through looking for the first match and breaking the loop when we find it. If we search without finding it anywhere in the array, **then** we add it...

```
NAME** array = calloc( MAX_NAMES, sizeof( NAME* ) );
int    count = 0;

int checkName(char names[])
{
    if(!count)
    {
        array[0] = calloc( 1, sizeof( NAME ) );
        array[0]->name = malloc((strlen(names) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(array[0]->name, names);
        count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(array[i]->name, names)==0)
            {
                printf("MATCH %s", names);
                break;
            }
        }

        if( i == count && count < MAX_NAMES )
        {
            array[count] = calloc( 1, sizeof( NAME ) );
            array[count]->name = malloc((strlen(names) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(array[count]->name, names);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code first tests to see that the array is not empty... if it is, then the first element is created for the array and the name is assigned.

Otherwise, it parses the array to see if any entry in the array already matches the name... if it does, it will break the loop and the `i == count` test will fail, so the name is not added.

If the loop finishes without matching the name, then the `i == count` test will return true and we add the new name to the end of the array, if there is room in the array.

Comment: I have created a struct shown below:

        typedef struct {
         char *name;
        } NAME;

        NAME  *array = NULL;

Comment: Above is how i check whether the names are the same to the ones in the array.

However i am getting weird results..

Here is my test data:
Jackie
Bob
Jackie
Jackie
Bob

The output is
Jackie
Bob 
Bob

Where is should be: 
Jackie
Bob

thanks for reply. sorry new to this

Comment: int checkName(char names[]){
         NAME tempStruct;

         int i;
         for(i = 0; i < Count; i++)
         {
          if(array == NULL)
          {
           tempStruct.name = malloc((strlen(names) + 1) * sizeof(char));
           strcpy(tempStruct.name, names);
          }
          else
          {
           if(strcmp(array[i].name, names)==0)
           {
            printf("MATCH %s", names);
            break;
           }
           else
           {
                                 //add
           }
          }
          break;
         }
        }

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your time and help will give it a go now. regards bob

Comment: Have you used "if(i = count) { insert } because it would be the end of the array?

Comment: Okay... I've edited my response to give you a more complete solution (again)... but at this point I'm starting to do the work for you. Hopefully the answer I've given paints a full enough picture for you.

Comment: accepting it as the answer would be appreciated if it has solved the problem for you... that way the thread is marked solved. But, only if the answer fixes the problem.